# Simulated "Nested" Navigation Controller in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I have a Navigation Controller in which for every row select, I push ViewController A. However, ViewController A is another table of items.

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to make ViewController A also act as a navigation controller, in which for ever row I select in ViewController A, I can push a view controller, which, we'll name ViewController B.

I tried to add a Navigation Controller object inside an existing Navigation Controller to no avail.

How will I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NavigationController has a rootController - in your case this is a some kind of table view controller. When you push view controller A - you use parent Navigation Controller. So you can push as many as you need view controllers via this "parent" navigation controller. Read carefully [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1) section of apple docs

Comment: does that mean I have to pass a reference to of the root view controller to the one the view controller I am pushing into the stack?

Comment: No, you can access your navigation controller from any controller which was pushed using navigationController property